# ai/h2o/extensions/stacktrace/StackTraceExtension:Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, h2o

I was running sparkling water when this occured.

This my version,totally meets the document's requirement.

```
jdk1.7.0_67
scala-2.11.5
hadoop-2.6.5
spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.6
sparkling-water-2.1.27
```

I used the command, started it successfully :

```
bin/sparkling-shell --conf "spark.executor.memory=1g"
```

And it shows this:

[image]

But when I use the next command, it went wrong.

```
Exception in thread "H2O Launcher thread" 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
ai/h2o/extensions/stacktrace/StackTraceExtension: 
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

This is the document provied by H2O.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sparkling water document:
http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.1/latest-stable/doc/requirements.html

Sparkling Water 2.1.27 is ok with jdk 1.7, but it only work successfully with jdk 1.8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this was a known bug and it's already fixed on the latest Sparkling Water for Spark 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3. You can download Sparkling Water from https://www.h2o.ai/download/